# Selected option in view when SIZE is greater than 1

Tags: html, html-select

How do you get the selected option to be in view on page load?

```
<select name="whatever" size="5">  
    <option value="1">1</option>  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
    <option value="4">4</option>  
    <option value="5">5</option>  
    <option value="6">6</option>  
    <option value="7" selected>7</option>  
    <option value="8">8</option>  
    <option value="9">9</option>  
    <option value="10">10</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: @Rudi: your choice to reject the suggested edit and only apply the format change is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280357/why-was-my-edit-rejected-by-community-user).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the item shown in the dropdown list to be the selected item when the page loads. By default behavior the selected view does in fact show "in view" on page load. What are you seeing that you do not expect?

note: your html should be

```
<option value="7" selected="selected">7</option>
```

to be a valid html tag.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the html to selected="selected".  It still is not in view on page load.

On the following page if I select "Grape" under "Common Family" it advances to the next page and highlights "Grape" however it is not in view when size is over 1.  How do I get it to scroll into view?
http://hikearizona.com/x.php?I=30&SUB_ID=&dex=1

Comment: Actually, `<option value="7" selected>` is correct; `selected="selected"` should only be used in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers I've tested (Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE7) scroll the contents to display the selected option.

**Edit:** Windows XP

Comment: Thanks, it works for me on FF & IE 6, not Chrome.  I'm on Ubuntu, so maybe it works for the majority of Window users.  At the very least this is good to know.